# Why isn't there a retraction map from a sphere to a cylinder?

Tags: general-topology

I'm taking topology and my professor mentioned that you can define an equivalent class on the cylinder where you identify all of the points on the top and bottom "cap" as one point, and any other points with themselves, which will give a quotient space that is equivalent to a sphere.

However, after we discussed the theorem where if you have a retraction map r from a topological space X to another , Y. and a surjective continuous map q from X to Y, such that qr = identity map on Y, then q is a quotient map.

But he then asserts that there is not retraction map from the sphere to a cylinder, and I am struggling to understand why that is the case.

Comment: Do you really consider the cylinder *with* top and bottom faces? That would already be homeomorphic to a sphere without requiring any indentifications.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the fact that in a sphere every loop retracts to a point, not in a cylinder where the top cap does not retract to a point. If there was a retraction between the both spaces the $r(cap)$ would retract to a point so would $qr(cap)=cap$ contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I may have misintereperted my professor, I think what he meant is that there cannot be any "Section" from the sphere to cylinder. So let q be the quotient map that maps the cylinder to the sphere, a section r:  Sphere to cylinder such that q * r = identity.